# IDE for C++ developers

Tags: c++, ide

What is the most popular IDE for C++? And library for windows?
What is about QT?

Comment: This question is completely incomprehensible. IDEs and Libraries are completely separate things. Asking if there are libraries without saying what you need them for is like walking into a Hardware store and asking if they have tools.

Comment: We try to avoid "most popular" questions here, and the most popular IDE would doubtless depend on the operating system in use.  The word "windows" here is ambiguous:  it could refer to some aspect of Microsoft Windows, or a graphical user interface.  If you have a question about Qt, please ask it more clearly.

Comment: Your question is to general. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers/18616#18616 regarding asking.

Comment: Don't use an IDE because of its popularity.  Use an IDE that has features that you need and use.  A popular IDE that is difficult for you to install, use or doesn't have the features you need is worthless to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best IDE for c++ is visual studio(if you are working in windows), but if you want to use Qt, QtCreator is also nice. but i can't get what do you mean "A library for windows"!